# Counterexample to class of sets being a field

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have some space, $\Omega$, and that some class of sets $F$ in $\Omega$ is closed under the formation of complements, and is closed under the formation of finite disjoint unions.

I'm looking for an example which demonstrates that $F$ need not be a field. A field has both the properties listed above, but is also closed under the formation of non-disjoint finite unions. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask, do you know whether such an example exists?  Where does the problem come from?

Comment: @saulspatz The Billingsley textbook Probability and Measure. We are prompted to show that the class of sets $F$ need not be a field.

Comment: Just try building an example with small finite sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $F=\{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\},\varnothing, \Omega\}$. Note that this is closed under complements, and there are very few disjoint unions, so that it is also closed under them.